# Video from Frames at the OS X Command Line or Python?

Tags: macos, python, ffmpeg, imagemagick, video-conversion

I am looking for a good way to turn a stack of images into a video **on the command line** or  **python**.  Here is my setup:

- OS X 10.6
- Sequence of images either in **png** or **pdf** format. (i.e. 001.png, 002.png, ...)
- Want output to be as uncompressed and high quality as possible.
- Want output in either `MPEG-4` or `avi`.

I am aware of `convert` (i.e. `ImageMagik`) and `ffmpeg` but have not have much luck with either thus far, so I'm hoping for some guidance.  Thanks!

Comment: What were the exact commands that you tried using `convert` and `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [qt_tools](http://www.omino.com/sw/qt_tools/). Also, if just a few times, you can open a folder of images in QuickTime and do it via the GUI.

Comment: `qt_export` from `qt_tools` is just what I was looking for.  Thannks!

Comment: `qt_export` also has a nice feature to launch the format dialog from QuickTime allowing for configuration without having to resort to command line options while getting familiar with the tool.

Answer (score 0):

The [code_swarm](http://vis.cs.ucdavis.edu/~ogawa/codeswarm/) folks do something similar, [here's](http://code.google.com/p/codeswarm/wiki/GeneratingAVideo) (step 4) an article how they generate a video from images, including the `mencoder` and `ffmpeg` command line arguments. I used it a while ago successfully on Ubuntu.